# fresh increment daily in groovy/java

Tags: java, datetime, groovy

I have a job that runs daily n number of times. Each time when it runs I need to create file with incremental value **Ex:** if it runs 2 times before I have to create 3.txt and send to server and Next day it has to start fresh from 1.
**Sample:**

```
today - 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt, 4.txt ....
tommorrow - 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt ..
overmorrow - 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt and so on
```

Challenges are 
1.I can't read the last file generated since it is sent to external server.
2. I cant persist file name in DB.

I tried many things with time on groovy/java but nothing helps. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: "i tried many things" - please add them (or at least explain them) since it would help to eliminate potential routes here

Comment: do you know n? is the file created at fixed interval (e.g. if n = 6, files are created at 0:00, 4:00, 8:00, 12:00, 16:00, 20:00)? Do the numbers have to be sequential (1, 2, 3) or would an increasing sequence be good enough (1, 17, 123)? If you need sequential, you may be able to send increasing numbers that the server renames appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for your comment bro. Please check the answer you requested 

1. N will change every day. 
2. File created at fixed interval but interval will change everyday.
3.Yes it is sequential.
4. It is an third party server So asking them and making change will not happen in my life span.

Comment: Is it possible to count how many times cron job has ran for given day?